# Fail to create json object in android

Tags: android, json, getjson

The error message :

```
12-09 12:59:37.101: D/IssueListRequest(3771): Fail: org.json.JSONException: Expected literal value at character 0 of /storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.xxxxxxxxx.xxxx/files/myProgram/issues.json
```

When I run the program

```
  JSONObject issuesList = new JSONObject(IRConstant.issuesList);
```

Json:

```
{
"211": {
    "host": "https:\/\/s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com\/production-source\/ChangSha\/2013\/12\/09\/0\/0\/A\/Content\/",
    "timestamp": 1386514507,
    "cover": ["15\/Pg015.png",
    "16\/Pg016.png",
    "1\/Pg001.png",
    "2\/Pg002.png"],
    "year": "2013",
    "month": "12",
    "day": "09",
    "issue": "2013-12-09",
    "id": "211"
},
"210": {
    "host": "https:\/\/s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com\/production-source\/ChangSha\/2013\/12\/08\/0\/0\/A\/Content\/",
    "timestamp": 1386415087,
    "cover": ["1\/Pg001.png",
    "2\/Pg002.png",
    "3\/Pg003.png",
    "4\/Pg004.png"],
    "year": "2013",
    "month": "12",
    "day": "08",
    "issue": "2013-12-08",
    "id": "210"
},
"209": {
    "host": "https:\/\/s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com\/production-source\/ChangSha\/2013\/12\/07\/0\/0\/A\/Content\/",
    "timestamp": 1386331278,
    "cover": ["1\/Pg001.png",
    "2\/Pg002.png",
    "3\/Pg003.png",
    "4\/Pg004.png"],
    "year": "2013",
    "month": "12",
    "day": "07",
    "issue": "2013-12-07",
    "id": "209"
},
"208": {
    "host": "https:\/\/s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com\/production-source\/ChangSha\/2013\/12\/06\/0\/0\/A\/Content\/",
    "timestamp": 1386255815,
    "cover": ["15\/Pg015.png",
    "16\/Pg016.png",
    "1\/Pg001.png",
    "2\/Pg002.png"],
    "year": "2013",
    "month": "12",
    "day": "06",
    "issue": "2013-12-06",
    "id": "208"
},
"207": {
    "host": "https:\/\/s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com\/production-source\/ChangSha\/2013\/12\/05\/0\/0\/A\/Content\/",
    "timestamp": 1386171227,
    "cover": ["15\/Pg015.png",
    "16\/Pg016.png",
    "1\/Pg001.png",
    "2\/Pg002.png"],
    "year": "2013",
    "month": "12",
    "day": "05",
    "issue": "2013-12-05",
    "id": "207"
},
"206": {
    "host": "https:\/\/s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com\/production-source\/ChangSha\/2013\/12\/04\/0\/0\/A\/Content\/",
    "timestamp": 1386082817,
    "cover": ["15\/Pg015.png",
    "16\/Pg016.png",
    "1\/Pg001.png",
    "2\/Pg002.png"],
    "year": "2013",
    "month": "12",
    "day": "04",
    "issue": "2013-12-04",
    "id": "206"
},
"205": {
    "host": "https:\/\/s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com\/production-source\/ChangSha\/2013\/12\/03\/0\/0\/A\/Content\/",
    "timestamp": 1385996534,
    "cover": ["17\/Pg017.png",
    "18\/Pg018.png",
    "1\/Pg001.png",
    "2\/Pg002.png"],
    "year": "2013",
    "month": "12",
    "day": "03",
    "issue": "2013-12-03",
    "id": "205"
},
"204": {
    "host": "https:\/\/s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com\/production-source\/ChangSha\/2013\/12\/02\/0\/0\/A\/Content\/",
    "timestamp": 1385909880,
    "cover": ["17\/Pg017.png",
    "18\/Pg018.png",
    "1\/Pg001.png",
    "2\/Pg002.png"],
    "year": "2013",
    "month": "12",
    "day": "02",
    "issue": "2013-12-02",
    "id": "204"
},
"203": {
    "host": "https:\/\/s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com\/production-source\/ChangSha\/2013\/12\/01\/0\/0\/A\/Content\/",
    "timestamp": 1385806902,
    "cover": ["1\/Pg001.png",
    "2\/Pg002.png",
    "3\/Pg003.png",
    "4\/Pg004.png"],
    "year": "2013",
    "month": "12",
    "day": "01",
    "issue": "2013-12-01",
    "id": "203"
},
"202": {
    "host": "https:\/\/s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com\/production-source\/ChangSha\/2013\/11\/30\/0\/0\/A\/Content\/",
    "timestamp": 1385720451,
    "cover": ["1\/Pg001.png",
    "2\/Pg002.png",
    "3\/Pg003.png",
    "4\/Pg004.png"],
    "year": "2013",
    "month": "11",
    "day": "30",
    "issue": "2013-11-30",
    "id": "202"
},
"201": {
    "host": "https:\/\/s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com\/production-source\/ChangSha\/2013\/11\/29\/0\/0\/A\/Content\/",
    "timestamp": 1385653656,
    "cover": ["1\/Pg001.png",
    "2\/Pg002.png",
    "3\/Pg003.png",
    "4\/Pg004.png"],
    "year": "2013",
    "month": "11",
    "day": "29",
    "issue": "2013-11-29",
    "id": "201"
},
"200": {
    "host": "https:\/\/s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com\/production-source\/ChangSha\/2013\/11\/28\/0\/0\/A\/Content\/",
    "timestamp": 1385566401,
    "cover": ["1\/Pg001.png",
    "2\/Pg002.png",
    "3\/Pg003.png",
    "4\/Pg004.png"],
    "year": "2013",
    "month": "11",
    "day": "28",
    "issue": "2013-11-28",
    "id": "200"
},
"199": {
    "host": "https:\/\/s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com\/production-source\/ChangSha\/2013\/11\/27\/0\/0\/A\/Content\/",
    "timestamp": 1385480533,
    "cover": ["1\/Pg001.png",
    "2\/Pg002.png",
    "3\/Pg003.png",
    "4\/Pg004.png"],
    "year": "2013",
    "month": "11",
    "day": "27",
    "issue": "2013-11-27",
    "id": "199"
},
"198": {
    "host": "https:\/\/s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com\/production-source\/ChangSha\/2013\/11\/26\/0\/0\/A\/Content\/",
    "timestamp": 1385393766,
    "cover": ["1\/Pg001.png",
    "2\/Pg002.png",
    "3\/Pg003.png",
    "4\/Pg004.png"],
    "year": "2013",
    "month": "11",
    "day": "26",
    "issue": "2013-11-26",
    "id": "198"
},
"197": {
    "host": "https:\/\/s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com\/production-source\/ChangSha\/2013\/11\/25\/0\/0\/A\/Content\/",
    "timestamp": 1385306370,
    "cover": ["1\/Pg001.png",
    "2\/Pg002.png",
    "3\/Pg003.png",
    "4\/Pg004.png"],
    "year": "2013",
    "month": "11",
    "day": "25",
    "issue": "2013-11-25",
    "id": "197"
},
"196": {
    "host": "https:\/\/s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com\/production-source\/ChangSha\/2013\/11\/24\/0\/0\/A\/Content\/",
    "timestamp": 1385204056,
    "cover": ["1\/Pg001.png",
    "2\/Pg002.png",
    "3\/Pg003.png",
    "4\/Pg004.png"],
    "year": "2013",
    "month": "11",
    "day": "24",
    "issue": "2013-11-24",
    "id": "196"
},
"195": {
    "host": "https:\/\/s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com\/production-source\/ChangSha\/2013\/11\/23\/0\/0\/A\/Content\/",
    "timestamp": 1385115154,
    "cover": ["1\/Pg001.png",
    "2\/Pg002.png",
    "3\/Pg003.png",
    "4\/Pg004.png"],
    "year": "2013",
    "month": "11",
    "day": "23",
    "issue": "2013-11-23",
    "id": "195"
},
"194": {
    "host": "https:\/\/s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com\/production-source\/ChangSha\/2013\/11\/22\/0\/0\/A\/Content\/",
    "timestamp": 1385048906,
    "cover": ["1\/Pg001.png",
    "2\/Pg002.png",
    "3\/Pg003.png",
    "4\/Pg004.png"],
    "year": "2013",
    "month": "11",
    "day": "22",
    "issue": "2013-11-22",
    "id": "194"
},
"193": {
    "host": "https:\/\/s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com\/production-source\/ChangSha\/2013\/11\/21\/0\/0\/A\/Content\/",
    "timestamp": 1384962195,
    "cover": ["1\/Pg001.png",
    "2\/Pg002.png",
    "3\/Pg003.png",
    "4\/Pg004.png"],
    "year": "2013",
    "month": "11",
    "day": "21",
    "issue": "2013-11-21",
    "id": "193"
},
"192": {
    "host": "https:\/\/s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com\/production-source\/ChangSha\/2013\/11\/20\/0\/0\/A\/Content\/",
    "timestamp": 1384875694,
    "cover": ["1\/Pg001.png",
    "2\/Pg002.png",
    "3\/Pg003.png",
    "4\/Pg004.png"],
    "year": "2013",
    "month": "11",
    "day": "20",
    "issue": "2013-11-20",
    "id": "192"
},
"191": {
    "host": "https:\/\/s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com\/production-source\/ChangSha\/2013\/11\/19\/0\/0\/A\/Content\/",
    "timestamp": 1384789257,
    "cover": ["1\/Pg001.png",
    "2\/Pg002.png",
    "3\/Pg003.png",
    "4\/Pg004.png"],
    "year": "2013",
    "month": "11",
    "day": "19",
    "issue": "2013-11-19",
    "id": "191"
},
"190": {
    "host": "https:\/\/s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com\/production-source\/ChangSha\/2013\/11\/18\/0\/0\/A\/Content\/",
    "timestamp": 1384703333,
    "cover": ["1\/Pg001.png",
    "2\/Pg002.png",
    "3\/Pg003.png",
    "4\/Pg004.png"],
    "year": "2013",
    "month": "11",
    "day": "18",
    "issue": "2013-11-18",
    "id": "190"
},
"189": {
    "host": "https:\/\/s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com\/production-source\/ChangSha\/2013\/11\/17\/0\/0\/A\/Content\/",
    "timestamp": 1384598514,
    "cover": ["1\/Pg001.png",
    "2\/Pg002.png",
    "3\/Pg003.png",
    "4\/Pg004.png"],
    "year": "2013",
    "month": "11",
    "day": "17",
    "issue": "2013-11-17",
    "id": "189"
},
"188": {
    "host": "https:\/\/s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com\/production-source\/ChangSha\/2013\/11\/16\/0\/0\/A\/Content\/",
    "timestamp": 1384511747,
    "cover": ["1\/Pg001.png",
    "2\/Pg002.png",
    "3\/Pg003.png",
    "4\/Pg004.png"],
    "year": "2013",
    "month": "11",
    "day": "16",
    "issue": "2013-11-16",
    "id": "188"
},
"187": {
    "host": "https:\/\/s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com\/production-source\/ChangSha\/2013\/11\/15\/0\/0\/A\/Content\/",
    "timestamp": 1384446978,
    "cover": ["1\/Pg001.png",
    "2\/Pg002.png",
    "3\/Pg003.png",
    "4\/Pg004.png"],
    "year": "2013",
    "month": "11",
    "day": "15",
    "issue": "2013-11-15",
    "id": "187"
},
"186": {
    "host": "https:\/\/s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com\/production-source\/ChangSha\/2013\/11\/14\/0\/0\/A\/Content\/",
    "timestamp": 1384356186,
    "cover": ["1\/Pg001.png",
    "2\/Pg002.png",
    "3\/Pg003.png",
    "4\/Pg004.png"],
    "year": "2013",
    "month": "11",
    "day": "14",
    "issue": "2013-11-14",
    "id": "186"
},
"185": {
    "host": "https:\/\/s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com\/production-source\/ChangSha\/2013\/11\/13\/0\/0\/A\/Content\/",
    "timestamp": 1384271440,
    "cover": ["1\/Pg001.png",
    "2\/Pg002.png",
    "3\/Pg003.png",
    "4\/Pg004.png"],
    "year": "2013",
    "month": "11",
    "day": "13",
    "issue": "2013-11-13",
    "id": "185"
},
"184": {
    "host": "https:\/\/s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com\/production-source\/ChangSha\/2013\/11\/12\/0\/0\/A\/Content\/",
    "timestamp": 1384184763,
    "cover": ["1\/Pg001.png",
    "2\/Pg002.png",
    "3\/Pg003.png",
    "4\/Pg004.png"],
    "year": "2013",
    "month": "11",
    "day": "12",
    "issue": "2013-11-12",
    "id": "184"
},
"183": {
    "host": "https:\/\/s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com\/production-source\/ChangSha\/2013\/11\/11\/0\/0\/A\/Content\/",
    "timestamp": 1384097295,
    "cover": ["1\/Pg001.png",
    "2\/Pg002.png",
    "3\/Pg003.png",
    "4\/Pg004.png"],
    "year": "2013",
    "month": "11",
    "day": "11",
    "issue": "2013-11-11",
    "id": "183"
},
"182": {
    "host": "https:\/\/s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com\/production-source\/ChangSha\/2013\/11\/10\/0\/0\/A\/Content\/",
    "timestamp": 1383994220,
    "cover": ["1\/Pg001.png",
    "2\/Pg002.png",
    "3\/Pg003.png",
    "4\/Pg004.png"],
    "year": "2013",
    "month": "11",
    "day": "10",
    "issue": "2013-11-10",
    "id": "182"
},
"181": {
    "host": "https:\/\/s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com\/production-source\/ChangSha\/2013\/11\/09\/0\/0\/A\/Content\/",
    "timestamp": 1383906143,
    "cover": ["1\/Pg001.png",
    "2\/Pg002.png",
    "3\/Pg003.png",
    "4\/Pg004.png"],
    "year": "2013",
    "month": "11",
    "day": "09",
    "issue": "2013-11-09",
    "id": "181"
}
 }
```

How to fix it? thanks

Comment: I don't think your json data is correctly formed. Is the syntax right?

Comment: rather then 209, 210,... give a fixed value for that like "data"

Comment: the json should be valid , I checked it on http://jsonlint.com/